# Mapping extensions and UTI on OS X

Tags: macos, finder

In OS X, an extension can correspond to one or more UTIs. The sample code gives an array for an extension.

```
NSArray *UTIs = (NSArray *)UTTypeCreateAllIdentifiersForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension,
(CFStringRef)extension,
nil);
```

So for `e1` there can be `u1`, `u2`, `u3`,…

Now there is a case where `e1`, `e2`, `e3` correspond to the same `u1`.

So I have 2 questions:

1. Is there a case where we have the following situation?

   ```
   u1: e1,e2,e3
   u2: e1,e4,e5
   u3: e4,e6
   ```
2. Based on this, if I have to set a default application for `e1`, which can be only set if I get `u1` and `u2`, will this work properly?

Comment: To prevent premature close votes: This question contains sample code, but appears to be on topic as a whole.

Comment: Manish, are you asking about general system behavior, or specifically about the the Objective-C APIs you're using?

Comment: I wrote a snippet of code to highlight that there can be multiple UTI's for a single extension.

Comment: So I am asking about a general system behavior and what logic OSX implements for setting a default application.